# Docker multiline CMD or ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a really long command line for the default process due to a number of arguments.   I think the easiest would be to create a script (for eg.`run.sh`) and then call this script in your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.  I'm wondering if there is a way to make your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` multiline (the way we write `RUN`).  For eg.

```
ENTRYPOINT["/path/myprocess",
           "arg1",
           "arg2" ]
```

I was thinking this is a valid syntax since the format is json. However, `docker build` throws the error

```
Step 14 : ENTRYPOINT[
Unknown instruction: ENTRYPOINT[
```

Is there a way I can split the `ENTRYPOINT` to multiple lines?

Comment: My mistake.  I missed a space between `ENTRYPOINT` and `[` .  I found that dockerfile supports multiline `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` by terminating the line with `\`; same as `RUN`.

Comment: Add the answer and accept it then :)

Answer (score 158):

It was a typo in the dockerfile.  I missed a `space` between `ENTRYPOINT` and `[`.  Dockerfile supports multiline `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` by terminating the line with `\`, same as `RUN`.  So, in my case it can be

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/path/myprocess", \
             "arg1",            \
             "arg2"             \
]
```

Comment: when I tried that with multiline CMD parts as 
    CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", \
      "java", \
      "-jar ..." \
    ]
, my linux docker 18.09.1 image run executed java without arguments. Had to switch to
    CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", \
      "java, \
      -jar ..." \
    ]
(removed quotes between multilined java args)